# how to get jquery Easy UI unminified files

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

i am trying to get unminified js and css files for Easy UI. 
i tried in easyUI web site.
**Basically i am trying to develop new data grid using JQuery Easy UI.**
can u please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy the commercial license which also sports the source code on http://www.jeasyui.com/contact.php .

Isn't it strange however, that a GPL product ships only the obfuscated version of something? I wonder if that complies with the letter of the GPL (certainly not with the spirit), my gut feeling would be it does not, but then, ianal - nor a thorough reader of the GPL...

Plus, jeasyui.com does not have any information on the author(s) of the software, except for the email address, which is all you seem to have when entering your credit card information to purchase it via PayPal. Judging from the English language skills on that website and what looks like Chinese to me in another project of his (http://code.google.com/p/etmvc/), it seems this is some one-man shop in China (which is fine with me, but I want to know before entrusting hundreds of dollars to that email address...)

The link in `akiller`'s answer has the real sources up to some point in 2010, probably not up to date.

**Update 2015-07-03** It [now styles itself](http://web.archive.org/web/20150223063738/http://jeasyui.com/contact.php) as much more than a one-man show (and features three distinct self-domained email addresses, [up from a single gmail address](http://web.archive.org/web/20120709175959/http://www.jeasyui.com/contact.php)):

> Our team currently have three core members and consists of about 10 software development engineers.

However

> We will take a long time to develop and improve our software.

;) Even though

> Our team works hard for you.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-easyui/source/browse/trunk/src/easyloader.js) this what you're after?

CSS is in the [themes folder](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-easyui/source/browse/trunk/#trunk/themes/default).